# Python Standard - counting unique values and stacking without numpy

Tags: python, list, numpy, count, unique

I have a my_list which looks like this:

```
[['root', '151.62.163.222'], ['tergul', '151.62.163.222'], ['root', '201.179.14.4'], ['root', '201.179.14.4'], ['admin', '201.179.14.4'], ['admin', '201.179.14.4'], ['lemming', '10.0.0.202'], ['lemming', '10.0.0.202'], ['lemming', '10.0.0.202'], ['lemming', '10.0.0.202'], ['lemming', '10.0.0.202'], ['lemming', '10.0.0.202']]
```

Now, I want to count the number of unique IP Adresses and stack them together with their counts. The result should be a list and look like this:

```
[['151.62.163.222', '2'],['201.179.14.4', '4'],['10.0.0.202', '6']
```

I have code that does this with numpy arrays:

```
  unq, count = np.unique(my_array[:,1], axis=0, return_counts=True)
  failed_per_IP = np.column_stack((unq, count))
```

I cannot use numpy as it is not installed on the server I am running it on. How would I do this using Python standard libraries and only lists?

Comment: One of the standard modules has a Counter class or function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Counter is good but if you are interested in a more in depth implementation you can use a dictionary and keep track of the counts as you traverse the IPs.

This is a good exercise but a cleaner approach definitely uses a counter.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

data = [['root', '151.62.163.222'], ['tergul', '151.62.163.222'], ['root', '201.179.14.4'], ['root', '201.179.14.4'],
 ['admin', '201.179.14.4'], ['admin', '201.179.14.4'], ['lemming', '10.0.0.202'], ['lemming', '10.0.0.202'],
 ['lemming', '10.0.0.202'], ['lemming', '10.0.0.202'], ['lemming', '10.0.0.202'], ['lemming', '10.0.0.202']]

result = [list(item) for item in Counter(address for _, address in data).items()]

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[['201.179.14.4', 4], ['151.62.163.222', 2], ['10.0.0.202', 6]]
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job:

```
from collections import Counter

lst = [['root', '151.62.163.222'], 
       ['tergul', '151.62.163.222'],
       ['root', '201.179.14.4'],
       ['root', '201.179.14.4'],
       ['admin', '201.179.14.4'],
       ['admin', '201.179.14.4'],
       ['lemming', '10.0.0.202'],
       ['lemming', '10.0.0.202'],
       ['lemming', '10.0.0.202'],
       ['lemming', '10.0.0.202'],
       ['lemming', '10.0.0.202'],
       ['lemming', '10.0.0.202']]
newLst = [t2 for t1, t2 in lst ]
print(Counter(newLst))
Counter({'10.0.0.202': 6, '201.179.14.4': 4, '151.62.163.222': 2})
```